# In a python dictionary how can I display the content of the key and value of the dictionary entry?

Tags: python

```
city = {"New York": 2, "Minnespolis": 2, 'thing ' : 3}
print(city)
for key in city:
    print(city)
```

Comment: `for key, value in city.items(): print(key, value)`

Comment: It is a dictionary, not a directory.  What do you want that `print(city)` doesn't do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Iterating over dictionaries using 'for' loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3294889/iterating-over-dictionaries-using-for-loops)

Answer (score 2):

Below I provide you with two option.
Also this iterable is called a dictionary not a directory, although this can be a typo, I'd like to point that out.

**Option1**
You can use `dict.items()`

```
city = {"New York": 2, "Minnespolis": 2, 'thing ' : 3}
for k,v in city.items():
    print(f'key: {k}')
    print(f'value: {v}')
```

---

**Option two** `use dict[key]`

```
city = {"New York": 2, "Minnespolis": 2, 'thing ' : 3}
for k in city:
    print(f'key: {k}')
    print(f'value: {city[k]}')
```

---

**output**

```
key: New York
value: 2
key: Minnespolis
value: 2
key: thing 
value: 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean to access the value by key?

```
city = {"New York": 2, "Minnespolis": 2, 'thing ' : 3}
print(city)
for key in city:
    print(city[key])
```